# Getting an error while installing a react app via npx with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

npx: installed 98 in 25.756s

Creating a new React app in D:\Javascript\React\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.5.x","coffee-loader'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dharma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-10T10_06_27_118Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\Javascript\React
Done.

Comment: What was the exact command that you ran?

Comment: Do you have npm and node installed?

Comment: npx create-react-app my-app i was run this command....

and i  did npm node installation process

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem. Please include minimal reproducible example and update your question to include the actual problem you're trying to solve

Comment: i didn't able to create react app that is my problem 
on windows 7

Comment: Please post your packaje.json file

Comment: didn't create file thats my problem

Comment: package-lock.json

{
  "lockfileVersion": 1
}